# Warning when compiling with clang++

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, clang++

When I compile the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    string m1;

    cout<< "enter your name: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,m1);

    cout << "Your name is: " << m1 << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It give the following warning:

> type of symbol `_main' changed from 32 to 512 in >C:\Users\KDesktop\AppData\Local\Temp\cc7XPBuL.o

Secondly, the compiler does generate an .exe file, but whenever I run it, the program crashes immediately. Can someone help me with this issue.

Thank you

Comment: a) Please use `#include <string>` and not string.h b) Either simply `return 0;` or `#include <cstdlib>` to define EXIT_SUCCESS.

Comment: c) Fix your indentation

Comment: And your `main` is not declared correctly regardless. Per C++ § 3.6.1 `main` has two defined declarations allowed by the standard: `int main()` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Anything else is non-standard.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric: `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined only in `<cstdlib>` and `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Although I agree that the conventional notation in C++ is to use empty parenthesis, using `int main(void)` is legal (see 8.3.5 [dcl.fct] paragraph 4: "... A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type void is
equivalent to an empty parameter list. ...").

Comment: @DietmarKühl I concur, its just a sucky habit. I never followed the std beyond 3.6.1 regarding `main()` as it seemed pretty concrete, and never considered 8.3.5 to be applicable to it since 3.6.1 already chiseled it. Excellent point, however. Thanks. It makes me wonder, is 8.3.5 intended to be applicable to `main()` as well, since it is, in fact, specified in 3.6.1 ?

Comment: And for the OP, did you [try it like this](http://ideone.com/LqvvKP) ?

Comment: Best guess: your toolchain is outdated or is linking against the wrong libc. What's probably happening is that the libc (or crtbegin) declares `_main` as one kind of external symbol, but your compiled program declares `_main` as some other kind of external symbol. When linked, the discrepancy is noticed; when run, the discrepancy probably causes the call to fail (e.g. wrong calling convention).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your toolchain is outdated. Older versions of LLVM used the wrong value for the function symbol type; the bug was fixed in late 2010. Here's the bug report: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8320

You should upgrade your LLVM; the problem will go away.

Comment: I'm rightnow using LLVM 2.8. I'll update to 3.3 ASAP. Can you tell me why doesn't the .exe file works?

Comment: No idea, but it probably has something to do with the old toolchain. You might, for example, be linking to the wrong runtime library.